# Strip header fields from a post request using $http in an AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an AngularJS app I'm posting a form to a payment gateway. I have a header field called "Authorization" to pass my session token to the backend API.

When trying to make a request to the payment gateway I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://transact.nab.com.au/test/directpostv2/authorise. Request
>   header field Authorization is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

When making the same request using Postman everything works fine, with a 200 status code.

I've created a plunkr for a quick demo which also gets a 200 status http://plnkr.co/edit/8Ts6s0VDTTUVVC9dbCJC

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: authoriseURL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data: nabPaymentData
}).
success(function (response, status, headers) {
    alert('Success:' + response + ' status:' + status + ' headers:' + headers);
}).
error(function (err, status, headers) {
    alert('Error:' + err + ' status:' + status + ' headers:' + headers);
});
```

Is there a way to strip header fields for one single post request?

Comment: You can strip header for every post request before it reach server using interceptor. But actually I don't get it why would you want to remove the header if it is needed.

Comment: I only want to remove the header for making the post to the external URL which is a payment gateway.

Would it be possible to intercept for just that one request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment above you can use interceptor to remove auth header only for request to payment gateway. The solution will be like this. First we define interceptor using factory. Later we push the interceptor in angular config.

```
app.factory('myInterceptor', ['$log', function($log) {
    return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      $log.debug(config.url);
      // if request to payment gateway, delete the auth header
      if(config.url.indexOf('https://transact.nab.com.au') > -1) {
        $log.debug('before deleting auth header');
        $log.debug(config.headers);
        delete config.headers.Authorization;
        $log.debug('after deleting auth header');
        $log.debug(config.headers);
      }
      $log.debug(config.url);
      $log.debug(config.headers);
      // do something on success
      return config;
    },


  };
}]);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `Authorization` field for just that POST request by setting it to `undefined`:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: authoriseURL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': undefined
  },
  data: nabPaymentData
});
```